# How do I load 1000 images from assets to viewpager adapter in Android? i am getting out of memory problem

Tags: android, android-viewpager, assets, android-image

I am trying to read multiple images from asset to view pager adapter by passing array list but when 100 images are loaded then I am getting out of memory problem? The link of code is https://www.selmanalpdundar.com/how-to-read-all-images-from-sub-folder-of-assets-in-android.html`

```
  ArrayList<Drawable> dr= new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    try {


        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        String[] images = assetManager.list("dogs");

        Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[images.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < 1200; i++) {
           InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("dogs/" + images[i]);
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);

            dr.add(drawable);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // you can print error or log.
    }
```

Comment: share your code.

Comment: I using Bitmap ArrayList when I am trying to load all images from assets to Bitmap Array then i am getting out of memory problem

Comment: I using Bitmap ArrayList when I am trying to load all images from assets to Bitmap Array then I am getting out of memory problem I am following this code but I am just adding ArrayList. https://www.selmanalpdundar.com/how-to-read-all-images-from-sub-folder-of-assets-in-android.html

Comment: Please post an example that demonstrates the issue you are having. Add your code to your question

Comment: @squareskittles See The Above Code

Comment: Probably `1000 images` is the issue. You might have to find better optimization logic to have minimum number of Bitmaps in memory at a time and still have the experience you want to have for the customer.

Comment: You can use glide library to show  images in viewpager.So memory problem is not there

Comment: just don't load them beforehand. Load right when you need the next one

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to load any significant number of bitmaps at one time without getting oom exceptions.

You will need to work out some logic for deciding what image you want to load next on the fly and pull it out of memory as and when you need it. Will depend on how the images are organised. If you're not already then I would suggest using an image processing library like Picasso or Glide. Both these have caching inbuilt to save you some trouble